# CGo: How to avoid code duplication in switch

Tags: go, cgo, code-duplication

```
func GetStationPropsByPage(page string) []NameIndex {
    var ni []NameIndex
    switch page {
    case "station_sys_props":
        for _, n := range C.gStationSysProps {
            if n.name == nil {
                break
            }
            ni = append(ni, NameIndex{
                Name:   C.GoString(n.name),
                No:     int(n.no),
                Type:   string(n._type),
                Remark: C.GoString(n.remark),
            })
        }
    case "station_app_props":
        for _, n := range C.gStationAppProps {
            if n.name == nil {
                break
            }
            ni = append(ni, NameIndex{
                Name:   C.GoString(n.name),
                No:     int(n.no),
                Type:   string(n._type),
                Remark: C.GoString(n.remark),
            })
        }
    }
    return ni
}
```

In the code above, how can I write the for-loop only once? The type of `C.gStationSysProps` is generated by the compiler, for example, `[24]main._Ctype_struct___0`, and is different than `C.gStationAppProps`

Another related question is that for this to work, the C side has this code in the header file:

```
extern NameIndex gStationSysProps[24];
extern NameIndex gStationAppProps[30];
```

Without having to interop with Go, the C code was:

```
extern NameIndex gStationSysProps[];
extern NameIndex gStationAppProps[];
```

If I keep it without the max index, the compiling will go smoothly, however, the Go side cannot get any items, i.e. the array/slice is **empty**.  Is it true that we have to specify array size in C in order to use CGo?